# Zoom SSRS Report to fit Web Part size

Tags: web-part, reporting-services, dashboard, report-viewer

I am creating a dashboard in SSRS made up of eight SSRS charts all displayed on a single page.

This page is to be resizeable / work on numerous screen resolutions.  I have made the SQL Server Reporting Services Report viewer Web Parts themselves resize to fit the available space, but how do I make the reports they are displaying zoom to fit the container size?

For example, if the browser width is small the reports are cropped

[image]

Yet if the browser is wide, there is a lot of whitespace available

[image]

(note these blocks are sized are the same on my screen, but the image is zoomed to fit the space on StackOverflow)

Does anyone know how to make these reports scale appropriately?